# Displaying a record in a report when selecting the record ID in a combo box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have almost finished a project and I would like some user options in the form. 
I would like to allow the user to select a product code and when selected, it will find the relative record in the table and then display all the information from that in a report.

Any ideas on the best approach to this would help me out massively.

Answer (score 1):

Use the combo box selection with [DoCmd.OpenReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as the *WhereCondition* option.

So if the report's record source table or query includes a numeric field named `product_code` and your combo box is named `cboProductCode` ...

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReport", _
    WhereCondition:="[product_code] = " & Me.cboProductCode
```

If the field is text rather than numeric, add quotes around the value in the *WhereCondition*.

```
    WhereCondition:="[product_code] = '" & Me.cboProductCode & "'"
```